# Modelisation of orbital space debris

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, centripetal-force

So I'm working on estimating the probability of a collision between debris and what is known as the Kessler Syndrome.
I'm just getting started and I'm having difficulties tackling this problem, especially when it comes to modeling the debris, considering how there are various types and sizes of debris.
The question which is puzzling me is how close should two debris be as to consider their encounter as an effective collision?
I've tried doing a geometric study, but it always ends up depending on the geometries of the debris which aren't necesarrily the same, so how should I model their geometry and how close do they have to be (relative to their size of course) so as to collide effectively?
Any insight and comment would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What is the application? That will help determine how much care you need to take. A graphics sequence is very different from a risk assessment.

Comment: I'm trying to do a sort of risk assessment of The Kessler Syndrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually doing collision detection between irregularly shaped objects is hard since it depends on their orientation. But one can approximate it using cross-sections.

Imagine at first that object 1 is point-like and passing near object 2. If we project the silhouette of object 2 on a plane orthogonal to the trajectory, there will be a hit if object 1 hits inside the silhouette. That silhouette has a certain area, which depends on orientation. But if we average over all orientations we will get a cross-section $\sigma_2$ (if one is super-serious for a particular object this can be done using Monte Carlo simulation to get a value). Now we can do the same for object 1, which after all isn't point-like, and get a cross section $\sigma_1$.

We can also simplify things by noting that if object 1 gets within $r\approx\sqrt{\sigma_1/\pi}$ of the silhouette of object 2 there will be an overlap. Hence the effective cross section for both objects will be $\sigma_{12}\approx \pi(\sqrt{\sigma_1/\pi}+\sqrt{\sigma_2/\pi})^2$. If the total area of the plane region object 1 is passing through is $A$, then the probability of a hit (assuming uniform distribution) is $\sigma_{12}/A$.

If we consider the case with two objects on potentially intersecting orbits there is hence one hit chance per period, with an area $A$ set by the uncertainty in the orbits (if known) or up to some limit set by orbital energy and parameters (if we don't know much). This gives you the rate of hits.

After a hit you will have debris on random orbits, with some initial distribution of velocities relative to the parent objects. These new orbits all start from the same position, so they will after one period come close to each other again. Presumably the velocity distribution can give you an initial uncertainty distribution for secondary hits.

However, if you get a proper cascade the number of fragments will grow a lot and this kind of "agent based" model will start to become inefficient. At some point you probably want to do something like use the Boltzmann equation to instead analyse the probability distribution across position and momentum space.